# How to declare WooCommerce support in your theme

Tags: plugins

I have built my own theme, which integrates quite well with WooCommerce, but I want to know how to properly get rid of the notification on top of my theme that said my theme didn't support WooCommerce / properly declare support (going a bit further than just clicking away the message).

Comment: wanted to answer my own question q&a style, but wpse won't let me...

Comment: Any error messages when you try to answer? Maybe there's a reputation threshold and you'll need to wait a couple of hours. But, please, come back later and do it :)

Comment: Good find. I was just configuring a theme to work with WooCommerce yesterday and can't believe I missed that `add_theme_support()` idea.  Though you can also just dismiss the notice and it will go away permanently.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Digging into the code that generates the notification (`current_theme_supports('woocommerce')`) gives the answer: place `add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );` in your functions.php

simple!

Answer (score 9):

Add below code in function.php file of your current theme.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup_woocommerce_support' );

 function setup_woocommerce_support()
{
  add_theme_support('woocommerce');
}
```

Comment: This post is 3 years old (☉_☉)

Comment: ...It's now 6 years old, and still useful for reference ;)

Comment: And yet it still can break your theme big time

Comment: @fish_r make that 8 -- to the day !

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it does not work
I also tried

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
```

function woocommerce_support() {
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}

I have placed in my wordpress childtheme /wordpress director the single-product.php which removed the add sidebar but the side bar still shows

I am stuck

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/267893)